# add a new tab containing a master-detail in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I created an app using the *Tabbed Application* template (without using a storyboard) and added several tabs along with their functionality.  Now I want to add another tab that will have *Master Detail* functionality.  There doesn't seem to be a way to use the *Master Detail* template without creating a new app.  I tried creating a new app with the *Master Detail* template just so I could look at the code it generates but I can't figure out how to incorporate that code into my existing tabbed app.  How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this... (Adding example to Phillip's answer)

```
MasterViewController *masterViewController=[[MasterViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
[masterViewController release]; //if not ARC

tabbarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController,
                                  viewController1,
                                  viewController2, 
                                  //More view controller objects, 
                                  nil];
[navigationController release]; //if not ARC
```

MasterViewController may contain a UITableView as subview or it may simply be a UITableViewCotroller (as you need Master-Detail flow.).

Comment: What if I want to use a NIB for my UITableViewCotroller?  Where do I load it?

Comment: You can use MasterViewController *masterViewController=[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 1):

On an iPhone, a master/detail structure is basically a table view controller embedded in navigation controller and another custom view controller that is pushed when selecting a cell in the table.

If you're doing this in code, init your table view controller, init the navigation controller with the table view controller as its root, and update the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` property.

Comment: If you look at the UITabBarController Class Reference it lists a number of sample projects.  I think the one called "TheElements" does the kind of thing you want in its app delegate class.

Answer (score 0):

to get your whished behaviour in storyboards drag a navigation control in and make THAT a 'child' of the tabbar